# Android x86 in Main Repo?

Tags: android, x86, android-x86

Today i found out that i can lunch a android x86 build for 4.0.x at the main android repo. 
I builded for the `vbox_full_x86-eng` target but all i got was the same images i get for a normal arm build. (but i think they are compiled with x86 tools but they just got packaged into the same images)

I also found no documentation or news that android is available for x86 now in the main repo, but it makes totally sense for all the tables etc... but how can i now create for example a virtualbox image? should i just create a single partition image from the created ones (`boot`, `system` and `userdata`) and run grub or something on it?